# java 正規表現 repalceAll を使っての後方参照置換について

Tags: java, html, 正規表現, xml

javaの正規表現での後方一致について教えてください。
`<tag_1><tag_2>${文字列_1}</tag1></tag_2><tag_1><tag_2>${文字列_2}</tag_1></tag_2>`
このような構成(上記のようなものが続く)になっている場合、
`<tag_1><tag_2>${文字列_1}</tag1></tag_2>`の部分を残して
`<tag_1><tag_2>${文字列_1}</tag1></tag_2><tag_1>${文字列_2}</tag_1>`
のようにしたいです。
この場合どうすればできるでしょうか。

Comment: 閉じタグの記述順がHTML的には正しくないように見えますが、質問文は意図したものでしょうか。

Comment: もう一点、「後方一致」ではなく「後方参照」ではないかと思います。

Comment: >閉じタグの記述順がHTML的には正しくないように見えますが、質問文は意図したものでしょうか。
ご認識の通りです。

Comment: すでに文字列になっているものに対して置き換えを行いたいです。